# why flatten and collect_list error in scala? with cannot resolve symbol

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that I am trying to flatten using scala.

```
+---------+-----------+--------+
|visitorId|trackingIds|emailIds|
+---------+-----------+--------+
|     a   |       666b|      12|
|     7   |       c0b5|      45|
|     7   |       c0b4|      87|
|     a   |  666b,7p88|        |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I am trying to achieve a dataframe which is grouped by the visitorID. Below is the format

```
+---------+---------------------+--------+
|visitorId|   trackingIds       |emailIds|
+---------+---------------------+--------+
|     a   |       666b,666b,7p88|   12,87|
|     7   |       c0b4,c0b5     |      45|       
+---------+---------------------+--------+
```

My code:

```
object flatten_data{


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[5]")
      .appName("Flatten_DF")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

       val df =  spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header","true")
      .option("delimiter",",")
      .load("/home/cloudera/Desktop/data.txt")
    print(df.show())
    val flattened = df.groupBy("visitorID").agg(collect_list("trackingIds"))
  }
}
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea and I am getting an error at "collect_list".
I read through many solution on stackoverflow where people have asked on how to flatten and groupbykey and have used the same collect_list. I am not sure why this is not working for me. Is it because of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

I reworked on your code and this seems to be working:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

   object flatten_data{

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    val someDF = Seq(
      ("a", "666b",12),
      ("7", "c0b5",45),
      ("7", "666b,7p88",10)
    ).toDF("visitorId","trackingIds","emailIds")


    someDF.groupBy("visitorID").agg(collect_list("trackingIds")).show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`collect_list` is a method defined in the `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` object, so you need to import it:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list
```

Alternatively, you can import the entire object, then you'll be able to use other functions from there as well:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Finally, the approach I personally prefer is to import `functions` as `f`, and use qualified calls:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => f}

agg(f.collect_list(...))
```

This way, the global namespace inside the file is not polluted by the entire host of functions defined in `functions`.